# Add New Combo Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am building cascading country, state and city list cascading combo. I need the below functionalities

1. Need to provide search functionality with dropdown and i am using [this](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) for that functionality.
2. Next, I need to provide user either to choose from existing dropdown values or enter new one. This can be done for both country and state when entering new city.

So my actual question is, is there any free plugin available for this functionality.

If not i have this implementation idea. I will add a option called `NEW` to dropdown and when user choose that, the text box will be shown for user input. And on submit i can take the value from `dropdown` if the textbox value is empty.

Any ideas for this implementation with `MVC4`

Comment: IN that same Chosen plugin you references, take a look at this thread http://goo.gl/QAMvz

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, i am just asking for any plugin available, and not asking for your code...

Comment: Sorry, there's no such ready to use plugin. You will have to write some code to implement this functionality. Thus my question: what have you tried? What difficulties did you encounter with the implementation that you would like to ask about?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, yeah thanks i will implement my own.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this. This provides both the search and add new option functionality

[SexyCombo](http://code.google.com/p/sexy-combo/)